# Swift function to return documents from Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Update 2:

Got this thing to work. Not as elegant as I expected, but works.

The final func is this:

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping ([MyModel]?) -> Void) {
    
    self.db
        .collection("data/userData")
        .order(by: "modified", descending: true)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("no documents \(String(describing: error))")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
          let result = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> MyModel? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: MyModel.self)
            }
            completion(result)
        }

}
```

Calling it like this:

```
fetchData() { arr in if arr != nil {
                //Attach it to vars or whatever
            }}
```

I'm accepting @workingdog answer.

---

Update 1:
Edit: Following @workingdog comment, I tried using this code:

```
func fetchMyData(completion: @escaping ([MyModel]?) -> Void) {
self.db
    .collection("data/userData")
    .order(by: "modified", descending: true)
    .addSnapshotListener { [self] querySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("no documents \(String(describing: error))")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
      let result = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> MyModel? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: MyModel.self)
        }
        completion(result)
    }
```

}

This does still not give me a solution as I'm trying to call this method from a different function but it crashes my app. But also, I only wanted to call it with "var myDocuments = fetchData()". The above code doesn't give me that (although I'm not even sure what I'm asking is possible).

---

I have this code/query that should return documents from Firestore:

```
func fetchMyData() {
    
    self.db
    .collection("data/userData")
    .order(by: "modified", descending: true)
        .addSnapshotListener { [self] querySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("no documents \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        
        print(documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> MyModel? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: MyModel.self)
        })
        
    }
    
}
```

---

I want this function to return the results instead of printing them. I tried to push them into a high-level variable (self.myDocuments) but this is no good when the project becomes bigger and lots of other functions try to run this query for their own needs.

---

I tried using:

```
return documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> MyModel? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: MyModel.self)
        }
```

But got this error message:

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

I understand that 'compactMap' can't return anything, but what else can I do to grab these documents and have 'fetchMyData' to return them?

Comment: i think it's ```func fetchMyData() -> [MyModel]{ ```

Comment: What's the relationship between querySnapshot?.documents and a guy that you so-call MyModel?

Comment: @RajaKishan - this gave me this error: 'ListenerRegistration' is not convertible to '[MyModel]'

Comment: @ElTomato I'm not sure I understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if "I want this function to return the results instead of printing them." means you expect one MyModel, then try something like this:

EDIT: returning an optional array of MyModel:

```
func fetchMyData(completion: @escaping ([MyModel]?) -> Void) {
    self.db
        .collection("data/userData")
        .order(by: "modified", descending: true)
        .addSnapshotListener { [self] querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("no documents \(String(describing: error))")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            let result = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> MyModel? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: MyModel.self)
            }
            completion(result)
        }
}
```

use it like this:

```
    fetchMyData() { results in
        if let modelArray = results {
            // do something with your [MyModel] modelArray
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now I get 'Cannot find 'queryDocumentSnapshot' in scope' for the queryDocumentSnapshot line

Comment: Cool, so few things: 1) I had to change escaping (MyModel?) to escaping ([MyModel]?). 2) I get a warning "Capture 'self' was never used" and 3) How do I actually use this function? when calling it, it expects me to Insert 'completion: <#([MyModel]?) -> Void#>'

Comment: use the function like this: `fetchMyData() { arr in
            if let myModelArray = arr {
                // do something with your [MyModel] myModelArray
            }
        }`    can you edit your question and show the code you are using now.

Comment: And added a comment.

Comment: so you did not change escaping to ([MyModel]?) as you said?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, forgot to update the post. Now it’s fixed.